# Can not retrieve a list of tables from an Oracle database - conn.GetSchema("Tables")

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, odbc

I need to retrieve the list the tables in an Oracle database that is defined by a DSN that is using the Oracle ODBC driver.

However, `OdbcConnection.GetSchema("Tables")` throws an exception `ERROR [HYT00] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation\n` or `ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1` after about 30 seconds.

```cs
using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Oracle in OraDB18Home1};Dbq=XE;Uid=system;Pwd=mypassword;"))
{ 
            connection.Open();
            //Also unsuccessful with "Views" and "Columns", but works with "DataTypes" and "Restrictions"
            DataTable schema = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
}
```

The database is newly installed and is not too big.

I can call [GetSchema()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema) without parameters to successfully retrieve all supported schema collections.

I can also successfully run a query against my database:

```
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM vendors")
{
           Connection = connection
};
OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: check [this](https://www.tekstream.com/oracle-error-messages/ora-01013-error-message/) out

Answer (score 0):

You should stop using ODBC. Use ODP.NET - this is gold standard Oracle .NET provider. And use "Managed" version, i.e. Oracle.ManangedDataAccess. This code below will work fine

```
var conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=server:1521/sid;password=pwd;user id=usr");
conn.Open();
var tbl = conn.GetSchema();
conn.Close();
Consile.WriteLine(tbl.Rows.Count.ToString());
```